# Program does not contain a static ‘Main’ method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#

What do I do if I just want to create a project which contains a bunch of library functions?  In other words no Main method is required.  It seemed to be compiling a minute ago and then I added another .cs file and now I am confronted with this error message.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a .NET Class Library project if you only want a library project.  If this is a project that already exists, you can set the Project Output type to a DLL ("*Class Library*") instead of an Executable ("*Windows Application*"/"*Console Application*") in the project properties.

Answer (score 4):

What type of project did you create?  It sounds like you meant to create a class library but accidentally created an executable assembly.  Ensure that you are in fact creating a class library assembly (i.e. ".dll" not ".exe").

If you aren't using Visual Studio and are compiling your code with `csc.exe` then make sure that you are specifying `/target:library` to compile your code into a library.

Comment: Note: for MSBuild, set the TargetType attribute on the Csc task.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make the project a Class Library type. I believe you can change the type of project in the project properties settings.

Answer (score 0):

or you could use the tried-and-true empty main method

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution. Really simple. You wrote the static void main with lower case. You should write it like this: static void Main()

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occured when we deleted `App.xaml` file from our project after the required method written due to that please ensure that your `App.xaml` file is in correct format with respective namespace and references, if it is not, create it and add it in your project.